# Why is my equals statement not working for my breadth first search

Tags: java, search, breadth-first-search

I am writing a program that is solving a 8 tile puzzle but I am not getting any out put, I am running the debugger and I am generating the right successors, one of which is the goal state that I want but when I compare them it does not say they are so my program just keeps looping and looping. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
public static void BFSSearch(Node start, Node goal) {
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(start);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node theNode = q.poll();
        if (theNode.equals(goal)) {
            Stack<Node> path = new Stack<>();
            path.push(theNode);
            theNode = theNode.getParent();
            while (theNode.getParent() != null) {
                path.push(theNode);
                theNode = theNode.getParent();
            }
            path.push(theNode);
            int stackSize = path.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++) {
                theNode = path.pop();
                theNode.printState();
            }
        } else {
            ArrayList<Node> successors = theNode.genSuccessors();
            for (int i = 0; i < successors.size(); i++) {
                Node newNode = new Node(successors.get(i).curr);
                if (newNode.equals(goal)){
                    System.out.println("found");
                }
                if (!checkRepeats(newNode)) {
                    ((LinkedList<Node>) q).add(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably, theNode is not equals to goal. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: How does the class `Node` implement `equals(Node other)`? Have you written that class yourself? If yes, please show it...

Comment: Probably `Node` does not override `equals(Object)`.